# Change x axis labels to hours (time) on geom_tile()

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-tile

Here is a `geom_tile` displaying hours and days of the week, how can it made to display each hour (i.e. 00:00 through to 23:00 on the x axis)?

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(hour, day, fill = value)) +
  geom_tile(colour = "ivory")
```

Currently it displays every fifth hour:

[image]

I have tried a bunch of different things, and would prefer a 'best practice' way (i.e. without manually generating labels), but in case labels are needed, here's one way to produce them `hour_labs <- 0:23 %>% { ifelse(nchar(.) == 1, paste0("0", .), .) } %>% paste0(., ":00")`

#### Data for reproducible example

```
df <- structure(list(day = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L), .Label = c("Sunday", 
"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"
), class = c("ordered", "factor")), hour = c(0L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 18L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 
23L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 
20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 13L, 14L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 15L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 11L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 
19L, 21L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 7L, 8L, 10L, 13L, 14L, 22L, 23L), value = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 13L, 13L, 24L, 
39L, 21L, 17L, 25L, 22L, 27L, 28L, 19L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
7L, 23L, 38L, 18L, 26L, 21L, 20L, 31L, 40L, 35L, 22L, 5L, 3L, 
2L, 7L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 17L, 13L, 23L, 24L, 19L, 31L, 13L, 35L, 
50L, 22L, 13L, 7L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 14L, 17L, 33L, 32L, 
32L, 25L, 29L, 27L, 38L, 26L, 11L, 8L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 14L, 21L, 24L, 22L, 25L, 26L, 23L, 58L, 36L, 26L, 6L, 3L, 
1L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, -116L), groups = structure(list(day = structure(1:7, .Label = c("Sunday", 
"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"
), class = c("ordered", "factor")), .rows = structure(list(1:15, 
    16:33, 34:51, 52:69, 70:88, 89:105, 106:116), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr"))), row.names = c(NA, 7L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way using `sprintf` to construct labels.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>%
  mutate(lab = sprintf('%02d:00', hour)) %>%
  ggplot() + aes(lab, day, fill = value) +
  geom_tile(colour = "ivory") + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

---

To complete the missing times apart from @Eric Watt's suggestion we can also use `complete`.

```
df %>%
  mutate(lab = sprintf('%02d:00', hour)) %>% 
  tidyr::complete(lab = sprintf('%02d:00', 0:23)) %>%
  ggplot() + aes(lab, day, fill = value) +
  geom_tile(colour = "ivory") + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

Comment: Quick question: `df` in this case happened to contain all hours 0 - 23. Do you know how to force all labels (0 - 23) if the original df *didn't* contain all those hours? (e.g. if it was missing any values for 4am, that time won't get generated, but what if we want it to be present in the final plot?)

Comment: Probably you can use `complete`. Note that your data is grouped in `dput` so you might need to `ungroup` first. 
So something like this might help. `df %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  complete(day, hour = 0:23) %>% mutate(lab = sprintf('%02d:00', hour)) %>% rest of ggplot code....`

Comment: Actually, there is no data in `df` for `17:00`. Using `sprintf` as in this answer skips a tick mark and the gap at the `17:00` position.

Comment: @EricWatt You are right. Actually, I liked your answer. I have updated mine with another alternative using `complete`.

Comment: Were this my data and I was trying to get a quick plot, I probably would have done a simple `paste(hour, ":00", sep = "")` to cast it into the format I wanted to plot it as, and then likely missed the missing `17:00` as well :) I've had that happen more than once, and have been trying to get in the habit of having time/date data stored and plotted as the right type for that reason. Definitely more of a pain at times though. Since the original question asked about 'best practices'...

Comment: @EricWatt when I created the bounty it was a thank you to Ronak for giving me another solution through a comment after he'd already provided a great answer. I wanted to award the bounty immediately but was prevented from doing so due to SO's inexplicable 24 hour delay on awarding a bounty to an existing answer. It seems to have worked out since Eric you noticed something both I and Ronak missed. So I will try to award the bounty twice: once to Ronak and once to Eric.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Even more SO bizarreness: for some reason it only allowed me to create a bounty of 100, not 50.

Comment: It's all sorted now. I will leave the comments here in the hope SO will address the unnecessary 24 hour delay and confusion it causes.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest making sure your data type is correctly representing your data. If your `hour` column is representing time in hours, then it should be a time based structure. For example:

```
df$hour <- as.POSIXct(as.character(df$hour), format = "%H", tz = "UTC")
```

Then you can tell ggplot that the x axis is a datetime variable using `scale_x_datetime`.

```
ggplot(df, aes(hour, day, fill = value)) +
  geom_tile(colour = "ivory") +
  scale_x_datetime(labels = date_format("%H:%M")) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

If you want a break for every hour, you can input that as breaks:

```
ggplot(df, aes(hour, day, fill = value)) +
  geom_tile(colour = "ivory") +
  scale_x_datetime(breaks = as.POSIXct(as.character(0:23), format = "%H", tz = "UTC"), 
                   labels = date_format("%H:%M")) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

You can also use the `scales` package which has handy formatting options such as `date_breaks`:

```
library(scales)
ggplot(df, aes(hour, day, fill = value)) +
  geom_tile(colour = "ivory") +
  scale_x_datetime(breaks = date_breaks("1 hour"), 
                   labels = date_format("%H:%M")) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

Comment: Note that your dataset did not have any rows with hour = 17. Because the datetime is numeric based, you get a x axis tick at 17:00 even though there is no data there.